# MediaRouteButton State unstable in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, chromecast

How to keep MediaRouteButton state and avoid disabled state on FragmentActivity

I have written a service to handle all cast sdk logic on fragment activities in my project. When created that MediaRouteButton is enabled and I'm able to connect but if I disconnect from cast device or do not select a device soon enough, the button is disabled and is shown in grey color. It may be related with the default route connection. I have tried setting a mediaRouteSelector and also leaving it with the default one. How to keep the MediaRouteButton state and keep it enabled. (Chromecast device is present in the same network, registered as dev device with the receiver ID etc)

```
// mButton.routeSelector = mediaRouteSelector
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(activity, mButton)
if(castContext == null) castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(activity.applicationContext)
setUpButton(castContext!!.castState, mButton)

Expected: MediaRouteButton state is kept (disabled avoided)
Actual: The MediaRouteButton is enabled and works for a while then disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was written in the [documentation for **`MediaRouteButton`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/mediarouter/app/MediaRouteButton):

> When the default route is selected or when the currently selected
>   route does not match the
>   [**`selector`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/mediarouter/app/MediaRouteButton#getRouteSelector()),
>   the button will appear in an inactive state indicating that the
>   application is not connected to a route of the kind that it wants to
>   use. Clicking on the button opens a
>   [**`MediaRouteChooserDialog`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/mediarouter/app/MediaRouteChooserDialog.html)
>   to allow the user to select a route. If no non-default routes match
>   the selector and it is not possible for an active scan to discover any
>   matching routes, then the button is disabled and cannot be clicked.
>
> When a non-default route is selected that matches the selector, the
>   button will appear in an active state indicating that the application
>   is connected to a route of the kind that it wants to use. The button
>   may also appear in an intermediary connecting state if the route is in
>   the process of connecting to the destination but has not yet completed
>   doing so. In either case, clicking on the button opens a
>   [**`MediaRouteControllerDialog`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/mediarouter/app/MediaRouteControllerDialog.html)
>   to allow the user to control or disconnect from the current route.